# How to find distribution of a grouped column with respect to another column in excel?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, correlation, analysis

Excel newbie and aspiring Data analyst, I have this [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F61gDiQXL7vPl7M5S69gjl76fOhITCwuWj79i2zFhZ0/edit?usp=sharing) and I want to find the distribution of City wise Shopping Experience. The column M has the shopping experience rated from 1 to 5.

**What I tried**

I am not able to google how to do this at all. I tried running correlation, but the in-built excel data analysis tool does not let me run it on non-numeric data, and I am not able to group the City cells either. I thought of replacing every city with numeric alias but I don't know how to do that either. How to search, or go ahead with this problem?

Update: I was thinking of some way to get this out of the cities column.

[image]

I am thinking this is better done in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, have just taken the cities and data to show averageif, sumif and countif:

[image]

I used Data validation to provide the list to select from.

Comment: I have updated  the question...I am not sure though if this is the only way. Is there a way to do this by python?

Comment: I don't know about Python, if you wanted a solution with Python, did you tag Python or just expect people to guess?

Comment: I did not where I would find the answer, but yes it was a shot in the dark. Apologies.

Comment: I am not able to create that select using data validation. Can you guide me a little please ?

Comment: Data validation, list, then select the cells containing the cities or just type them in with commas as separators.